# Cron run my Python script but nothing is happening

Tags: python, csv, cron

I want to run a Python script every night at 12:00 am to clean up a csv file which is automatically filled in during the day by another script.

My csv file *code_list.csv* content looks like this at the end of the day:

```
87698
63753
19742
89876
62765
79832
# etc.
```

I use the `truncate` method to clean the csv file with this script *csvclean.py* :

```
import csv

filename = "/root/folder/code_list.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

and here is my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 0 * * * cd /root/folder && /usr/bin/python3 ./csvclean.py
```

Both files are located in the same folder `/root/folder`.

I can see in `/var/log/syslog` that the cron is running at the scheduled time but nothing is happening inside my *code_list.csv* file. While if I run the script directly using `python3 csvclean.py` it cleans up the csv file perfectly.

What have I forgotten?

**- EDIT -**

I used a method found here to retrieve logs.
I edited my crontab like this:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /root/folder && /usr/bin/python3 ./csvclean.py > /root/folder/csvclean.log 2>&1
```

and I added this line at the beginning of the *csvclean.py* script:

```
print 'starting'
```

I opened the *csvclean.log* file after the cron and I saw:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file './csvclean.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Which made me realize that my Python script file name is *cleancsv.py* and not *csvclean.py*.

It was under my eyes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command: `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

after setting crontab demon has to restart.

Also check `sys/log` for tracing what is issue while running script.

Comment: I tested this and modify my cron whith `*/1 * * * * cd /root/folder && /usr/bin/python3 ./csvclean.py`. Same result, the cron is running but no effect inside my csv file.

Comment: any error in log ? `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/crontest.py` something like add your direct path of file.

Comment: Found it! See my edited post above: the Python script file name is simply different

Comment: Good to know. at least log help you to find out what is causing.